# Limits at infinity with exponentials

Tags: limits

I have never come across this type of problem so far and am lost on how to proceed. I was told never to plug in infinity because it can get theoretical. $\infty-\infty=0$? $e^0=0$?

Problem: $$\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x-x^2}$$

Comment: Note: $\infty-\infty$ isn't zero, it can be any number you'd want it to be, so it is not a useful concept. Also $e^0=1$, not $0$.

Comment: What happens to the expression at x=1?  What happens at x=2? At x=3? Keep increasing x?  Is the value of the expression monotonically decreasing?

Comment: Note that $e^{x-x^2}=e^{x^2(\frac{1}{x}-1)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{x \to \infty} x - x^2 = -\infty$ so if we set $u = x - x^2$ we have

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{x - x^2} = \lim_{u \to -\infty} e^u = 0. $$

Comment: As a matter of courtesy, since your answer is more complete than mine, should I delete my answer?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky: Nah, it's OK. It often happens that people post answers at the same time that looks similar. Let the OP decide what he prefers.

Answer (score 1):

When evaluating a limit, you do not, strictly speaking, "plug in infinity" (although you'll be using your intuition to do so).  You are correct.  Consider the following:

$$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(x-x^2)$$

In this case, we see that the limit is $-\infty$.  Then, $e^{-\infty}$ = 0, as you specified.

Answer (score 0):

${lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}x-x^2}=lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}(-x^2)=-\infty$
$lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}e^{x-x^2}=e^{-\infty}=0$

Answer (score 0):

$ \lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x-x^2}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{e^x}{e^{x^2}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{e^{x^2-x}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{e^{x(x-1)}}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0$

Answer (score 0):

Using the inequality $e^x\ge 1+x$, which I showed in [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality, we can write

$$0\le e^{x-x^2}=\frac{1}{e^{x^2-x}}\le \frac{1}{1+x^2-x}$$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x-x^2}=0}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark